# Does sendto or connect arbitrarily assign an address and a port to the socket?

Tags: c++, sockets

I was wondering when a socket will get its address and port if I don't call `bind`. Does `sendto` or `connect` assign one to the socket if it doesn't have one already? Plus for listening socket if I don't call `bind`, does it mean I will never get anything from `accept` or `recvfrom` (because it doesn't have an IP address or a port)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `connect()` and `sendto()` perform an implicit bind if you do not call `bind()` explicitly.  They will bind to an available random ephemeral port on whichever network adapter has the least-cost route to the destination address.

You cannot call `accept()` or `recvfrom()` on a socket that is not already bound, you will get an error.  They do not perform an implicit bind.  You must be explicit about what you want to listen on.